# Android ongoing notification area - linking values with pictures to show at the notfication area

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I want to create a live ongoing cpu(and/or)ram notification with pictures but i dont know how to link pictures with the values taken from the system.

Example images:

For idle --->http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/840/idleq.png/

for 10 to 24% --->http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/841/18037282.png/

for 25 to 49% --->http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/267/74169930.png/

for 50 to 79% --->http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/692/63885257.png/

for 80 to 99% --->http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/20/39599298.png/

for 100% --->http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/715/100to.png/

Sorry for using imageshack.us but i cant upload images yet.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* you can change the pictures on the notification, but you can create multiple notifications and call them as you see fit. There may be a better answer, but this should suffice.

**Methods to create and destroy notifications**

```
private NotificationManager notificationManager;

/* Params:
 * int imageResourceId: The resource image to set
 * String titleText: the title of the notification
 * String statusText: the subtitle of the notification
 */
public void createNotification(int imageResourceId, String titleText, String statusText)
{
    Notification notification = new Notification(imageResourceId, titleText, System.currentTimeMillis());
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, titleText, statusText, null);

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}

/* Destroys all notifications */
public void destroyNotification()
{
    if (notificationManager != null)
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```

Ok, so this covers creating and deleting the notification, how do you change it for varying battery percentages? Simple, something like this depending on your image resources.

**Usage Sample**

```
if (batteryPercentage > 85)
{
    destroyNotification();
    createNotification(R.drawable.highBatteryIcon, "Good Battery", "85-100%");
}
else if (batteryPercentage <= 85)
{
    destroyNotification();
    createNotification(R.drawable.lowBatteryIcon, "OK Battery", "0-85%");
}
```

Put all your images in your drawable folder and modify the code as needed for all your percentages,etc, etc. But that's how I would do it personally.

Also, you can show things like dynamic percentage by updating the latestEventInfo for the notification and re-notifying the notificationManager, but you can have that fun ;)

Comment: So if i get it correctly:
Each "image" is a notification.
Each time the value is changed the previous notification is destroyed and replaced by the newest one.